# How do I diagnose an SSD with no apparent reportable errors?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have a desktop system running Windows 10 with multiple drives. One is a [Samsung 850 EVO 1 TB](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-75E1T0B/AM) dedicated entirely to my Steam library.

Steam has been giving me errors lately: disk write error when updating some games, and as of yesterday, *none* of my games can sync with the Steam cloud. Right now I am **not** asking about Steam: I would like to ensure the drive itself is healthy and that is what I am asking about here.

What I have tried:

- Windows `CHKDSK E: /scan` and right-clicking the drive in Explorer, tools, and checking for errors. Both come back clean.
- Viewing SMART data via [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/) indicates no failing checks.
- Running Samsung Magician per [this question](https://superuser.com/q/884073) indicates no errors (this tool also checks SMART parameters and knows how to interpret them for this drive)
- Swapping SATA ports and cables per [this question](https://superuser.com/q/367288) changes nothing.
- Checked the firmware: this drive is running the latest firmware version.
- I have opened files in the Steam library to ensure permissions are fine and they look correct (e.g. an executable should have a lot of non-human-readable bits with strings such as "cannot run in DOS" near the start, XML/JSON files look correct).
- Using the drive outside of Steam works as expected. If I write files to it, they can be read without error. I have written large (tens of GB) files and compared them to versions stored on other physical disks without error.

What other steps can I take to rule out hardware problems with my SSD? Is there an equivalent of a HDD surface scan for an SSD? Some other test or check I can run?

How do I rule out hardware error as a root cause of the errors I am seeing in Steam?

Comment: Things you can try: 1. Open one of the existing (Steam) files. Don't care about the contents, or the program (you can use Notepad), just see if you have correct permissions. *Don't* do it as admin. --- 2. Install a (small) game or program via Steam, and see if it works. Since you have this problem *only* with Steam, it may not be an actual hardware failure.

Comment: @NathanShiraini I forgot that part, I have spot-checked some of the files in the library especially for games that are unable to update. Obviously I cannot hand-check everything. Also, I understand this is _most likely_ not a hardware failure: I simply want to be sure I have checked everything I can because as soon as I ask about Steam errors on Arqade or the Steam forums the first question will be "are you _sure_ the SSD is not faulty?"

Comment: one trick which I have used to confirm suspected *optical drive* errors in the past was to make a very large zip file on optical media. ZIP is very intolerant of CRC/checksum erors and will complain. In some cases, copying that file off the drive multiple times would result in a low percentage of correct copies, with the others failing the crc check(s) when unzipping. Note that file caching may interfere with such a test: the file copy procedure may use the memory copy rather than reaccessing the drive.

Comment: Perhaps Steam is encountering the write error while updating lists that are NOT on that Steam Library drive.  So, to that end, you should also check your other drive(s) (specifically, the one that actually houses Steam, usually in  `C:\program files (x86)`)

Comment: Both SSDs containing Steam data (Steam itself is installed on the OS drive) check out fine.

Comment: I was able to resolve the Steam errors, and it looks like I did pretty much everything I could to troubleshoot the SSD.